# Qt: how to define Cmd+key shortcut for MAC

Tags: macos, qt

I'm absolutely new to Qt.

How do I define a `Cmd + numeric key` key sequence on Mac in code?

For Windows I have

```
QKeySequence(QString("Ctrl+") + QString::number(number));
```

where `number` is, say, 2

What should be the same for a MAC `cmd` key?

And, is it possible for Qt to determine somehow if we are running on Mac or Windows (so I could create key sequence as appropriate)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As noted in the [`Qt::Modifier` enum documentation](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtjambi-4.5.2_01/com/trolltech/qt/core/Qt.Modifier.html):

> Note: On Mac OS X, the CTRL value corresponds to the Command keys on
>   the Macintosh keyboard, and the META value corresponds to the Control
>   keys

The [`QKeySequence` documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html) is more detailed:

> Note: On Mac OS X, references to "Ctrl", Qt::CTRL, Qt::Control and
>   Qt::ControlModifier correspond to the Command keys on the Macintosh
>   keyboard, and references to "Meta", Qt::META, Qt::Meta and
>   Qt::MetaModifier correspond to the Control keys. Developers on Mac OS
>   X can use the same shortcut descriptions across all platforms, and
>   their applications will automatically work as expected on Mac OS X.

So if you are just using `Ctrl` on Windows/Linux and `Cmd` on MacOS, you don't need to change anything just use the Windows sequence.

Comment: You mean it should be like QKeySequence(QString("Cmd+1")) on Mac? I just don't have a Mac on me to check, sorry.

Comment: No, the "Ctrl" token maps to `Qt::CTRL` which is regarded as the "Cmd" key on Macs, so `QKeySequence(QString("Ctrl+1"))` is read correctly regardless of the platform.

Comment: Just noting that in Qt 6.4 on Mac Qt::CTRL maps to Ctrl and Qt::META maps to Command